# phplist email not sending webmaster@fall-pac.com : Called Mail() without being connected

Tags: phplist

I am getting this error (phplist email not sending webmaster@fall-pac.com : Called Mail() without being connected) since upgrading my phplist nothing else has change I have sent a test email from the actual smtp mail box and it works so I know it not the email address I think it must be somthing in my config.php file but cants seem to find what could be causing the issue any help would be great please see my config.php i Have put on pastbin as its to big put here http://pastebin.com/CjRKdu5H

Comment: Also I have just removed the SMTP and it works sending from the php standard mail but my hosting will not let us send marketing emails this way

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

 require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail 
    //if  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    // use $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = 'username';  
    $mail->Password = 'password';           
    $mail->SetFrom('xyz@some.com', 'Testing');
    $mail->Subject = 'Yii Test';
    $mail->Body = "hello";
    $mail->AddAddress('xyz@some.com');
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        echo $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
?>
```